# How can I easily validate a deeply nested object property exists?

Tags: javascript

In many places in my code I do the following to access deep nested properties:

```js
if (a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d) {
    //do something with a.b.c.d
}
```

Given a, b, c and d have more complex names this is ugly, time consuming and opens places for mistakes to occur.

Is there a "sugarcoating" way to handle this? something like:

```js
if (valid(a.b.c.d)) {
    //do something with a.b.c.d
}
```

Comment: You could use `try/catch` but it has performance penalty

Comment: lodash has the `_.get`: https://lodash.com/docs#get

Comment: Such functionality is not natively supported (even in ES6). But you can use libs, for example: https://lodash.com/docs#get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make recursive helper function to do this, for example:

```
function valid(obj, chain) {
    if (!chain.length) {
        return true;
    }
    var prop = chain.shift();
    return !obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? false : valid(obj[prop], chain);
}

var a = { b: { c: { d: 1 } } };

console.log(valid(a, ['b', 'c', 'd'])); // true
console.log(valid(a, ['b', 'c', 'e'])); // false
```